# How to send commands from website using Xively?

Tags: javascript, html, xively, mbed

I am trying to create a simple website to get some floats and send some commands back to a ST Nucleo F401RE programmed on mbed. I can use the xivelyjs documentation to recieve datastreams (floats) but don't know how to send anything back. 
Here is my code to get the floats:

```
<div><small>Temperature:</small> <span  style="color:black" id="element1"></span></div>
<div><small>Trip Level:</small> <span style="color:black" id="element2"></span></div>
<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include XivelyJS -->
<script src="http://d23cj0cdvyoxg0.cloudfront.net/xivelyjs-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) 
{

  // Set the Xively API key (https://xively.com/users/YOUR_USERNAME/keys)
  xively.setKey( "KEY" );

  // Replace with your own values
  var feedID        = FEED,          // Feed ID (the last number on the URL on the feed page on Xively)
      datastreamID  = "Temperature";       // Datastream ID
      selector1     = "#element1";   // Your element on the page - takes any valid jQuery selector
      datastreamID2 = "Trip_Level";
      selector2     = "#element2";
// Get datastream data from Xively
  xively.datastream.get (feedID, datastreamID, function ( datastream ) 
  {
    // Display the current value from the datastream
    $(selector1).html( datastream["current_value"] );
    // Getting realtime! The function associated with the subscribe method will be executed every time there is an update to the datastream
    xively.datastream.subscribe( feedID, datastreamID, function ( event , datastream_updated ) 
    {
        // Display the current value from the updated datastream
        $(selector1).html( datastream_updated["current_value"] );
    });
  });

  xively.datastream.get (feedID, datastreamID2, function ( datastream ) 
  {
    $(selector2).html( datastream["current_value"] );
    xively.datastream.subscribe( feedID, datastreamID2, function ( event , datastream_updated ) 
    {
        $(selector2).html( datastream_updated["current_value"] );
    });
  });
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `xively.datastream.put()`.